# Open a Spatialite database in PHP

Tags: spatialite, php, sqlite

I need to open a Spatialite database by using php in a php's framework. I've already work on a basic php file to test how it work but it gave me some errors.

I've already try to load extension by using two method :

- $db->loadExtension('mod_spatialite.so');
  Warning: SQLite3::loadExtension(): Not supported in multithreaded Web servers in C:\applications\www\sqlite3_ext\index.php on line 19
- $db->exec("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite.so')");
  Warning: SQLite3::exec(): not authorized in C:\applications\www\sqlite3_ext\index.php on line 20

Utilities :
Use a wamp (3.0.0) for a local server
 - PHP 7.0.0
 - Mysql
 - Apache 2.4.17

Link to my basic php code : https://pastebin.com/t01D7xrg
Link to my php.ini configuration : https://pastebin.com/HrTjnWPP

Answer (score 1):

I had same trouble with the sqlite extensions loading and decide to create own shell and native php drivers and compile some win/lin binaries for here: https://github.com/eSlider/spatialite

I wrote some tests you can use as an example:
https://github.com/eSlider/spatialite/blob/master/tests/SpatialShellDriverTest.php

By initializing instance of SpatialShellDriver you can add own spatialite library and/or spatialite binary path.

It should be posible to work without any problem if you use composer dependency manager.
Take a look on this here: https://getcomposer.org/

Here the installation informations:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Notice: SpatialShellDriver is slow, but it works on windows and linux without any additional installation.
For linux you can use SpatialNativeDriver if you install spatialite php module.